# UIWebView inside full screen UICollectionView with paging

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview

I want to have a full screen UICollectionView with paging, with a UIWebView in every cell.
The WebView should scroll up and down, and the CollectionView should move pages left and right.
Also, I want the pages on the cells will preload so when the user move to a certain page the html page will already be there.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as expected since a UIWebView can have content that scrolls vertically and horizontally and the horizontal scrolling might cause problems for the collection view. I'll try and set it up real quick and post a solution if it works. :)

Comment: I'm the one creating the HTML - so - no horizontal scrolling

Comment: Like UITableView, UICollectionView is reusable, so I think you can't do it with UICollectionView. How about manually place UIWebViews in paginated UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to put it all in here, so check out if [this project](https://github.com/jurezove/web-view-collection) gets you closer to solving your problem.

Notice that there is no preloading, because if you'll write your own html and there won't be any network calls, you don't need to preload pages - changes will be instantly visible to your users.

Answer (score 0):

You always gonna have to reload the UIWebView in UICollectionViewCells because they are reusable, but if you want you can make a hack, an UICollectionView that it is 3 times bigger than the frame of your main view it has to begin in the second page and finish in the one before the last.
It is going to have always 3 webviews preloaded (but you can make the hack bigger if you want) or you can make a UIScrollView with pagination activated which always gonna have all of the webview preloaded.